# d3.join() enter called instead of update?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

I'm trying to make D3 update an SVG element once a second by passing a fresh `Date` object into the `data()` function, followed by `join()` to update the page. I'm actually doing this in an [Observable](https://observablehq.com/) notebook using `Promises.tick()` but I think the code below ([full source](https://gist.github.com/markdrayton/93a7eeee496fdd193b1819758900a2d5)) is a rough approximation of the relevant bits. My end goal is to make a clock but the code here is a minimal demo of the issue I have.

The problem with this code is that the `update` function in `join()` is never called -- every time around the loop the `enter` function is called instead, which results in a fresh `text` being appended each time. Since I have one datum and one element I would expect `join`'s `update` to be called, not `enter`. I am aware that the key function on `data()` ([example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221)) is significant in determining what has changed but my understanding is that the default key is the array index, which should always be 0 here. At any rate, specifying a different key function (ranging from the identity function to returning a constant) hasn't helped.

```
while (true) {
  var data = [new Date()];

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("text").text(d => "enter: " + d),
      update => update.text(d => "update: " + d)
    );

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this:

```
svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  //etc...
```

You are **appending** a new `<g>` element every time you run the loop, and all the selected elements (texts, or whatever) after that will reference that newly appended group, that is, the `selectAll` selects all texts **inside** that newly appended group. Obviously, there is none. That's why you always have only an enter selection, but no update selection.

Have a look at this demo, reproducing your problem:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");

function foo(data) {
  var div = body.append("div")
    .selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("p").html(d => "enter: " + d),
      update => update.html(d => "update: " + d)
    );
};

foo([Math.random()]);
d3.interval(function() {
  foo([Math.random()])
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Supposing that you want to append the group **only once**, you can do something like this:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".myGroup")
  .data([true]);

g = g.enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .merge(g);

g.selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .join(
    enter => enter.append("text").text(d => "enter: " + d),
    update => update.text(d => "update: " + d)
  );
```

Here, `data([true])` indicates that the data itself doesn't matter, it is just a single truthy value, for appending a single group element.

Here is a demo showing how it works:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");

function foo(data) {
  var div = body.selectAll(".myDiv")
    .data([true]);

  div = div.enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "myDiv")
    .merge(div);

  div.selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("p").html(d => "enter: " + d),
      update => update.html(d => "update: " + d)
    );
};

foo([Math.random()])
d3.interval(function() {
  foo([Math.random()])
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```